# Can I place my script in /usr/bin?

Tags: linux, debian, command

I wrote a small bash script for starting, stopping and restarting my java applications and I want to make it available to all users so they could run it.
Should I just place it in `/usr/bin` to do that? Is it the right place for my scripts? Isn't that for like installed package script and stuff only?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Correct, `[/usr]/[s]bin` is for the distro creator's use. Local user scripts belong under `/usr/local`, specifically `/usr/local/bin` in this case.

[Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend putting it in `/opt`. You can create directory with your application name under `/opt` and then `bin` directory under it, so your path will look like that:

```
/opt/<your_app_name>/bin
```

Then you create two scripts in `/etc/profile.d` - `<your_app_name>.sh` and `<your_app_name>.csh` and in those scripts you add the path above to global `$PATH` variable to make executables of your app available to all users. That's all.

I think that this approach is cleaner then putting it in `/usr/local/bin` since all your changes to the system are localized to a single directory (with exception of two scripts in `/etc/profile.d`), it is easy to remove your app manually and your files do not mix with files of other applications (which may be the case with `/usr/local`). This approach is also compliant with ["Filesystem Hierarchy Standard"](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly nothing preventing you from placing a script in /usr/bin, giving it world-execute permissions (something like `chmod 755`) and allowing users to run it.  If you want to conform with "The UNIX way" there are more appropriate locations.  I'm sure I'll start a trail of comments on why this is wrong, but I'd learn towards storing it in `/usr/local/bin/` instead.  The `/usr/local` directory is typically for software not managed by the distribution directly, such as third party applications or scripts.

Comment: Actually, `/usr/local` is for second-party stuff. Third-party stuff goes under `/opt`.